# Is there a way make HTML code independent from changes in CSS class names?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am using [Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com) for a while, but now  [Twitter Bootstrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com) is coming. And new `Twitter Booststrap` [comes with some changes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/), like renaming `.table-condensed` to `.table-sm` for example. For sake of future possible migration from current to future version, is there a way to make HTML code independent from changes in CSS class names?
For example, if I have `.table-condensed` class, is there a way to create my own class `table-small` and create it from existing `Twitter Bootstrap`'s class `table-condensed`? Something like (pseudo-code):

```css
.table-small {
    join(".table-condensed")
}
```

I use only pure `CSS` until this moment (I am Front-End Developer occasionally rather than full-stack:) ), if anybody will answer me if this thing is even possible in some way, maybe with preproccesors or something like that, I would be very grateful - thank you in advance !

Comment: @cvrebert: I notice you're adding the [bootstrap-4] tag to questions with [twitter-bootstrap-4]. Is there a reason you're not also removing the latter tag? We don't need multiple tags for the same thing. Has this been discussed on meta yet?

Comment: "Is there a way make HTML code independent from changes in CSS class names?" No, because CSS is coupled to the document language by design. Without any knowledge of the document structure, selectors aren't going to work. You can't expect CSS to know exactly which element to style if you don't tell it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SASS then you can use the `@extend` function.

However, it's recommended to avoid doing this as it copies the selected class into the new one thus, essentially, doubling the size of your CSS

The solution is either to not upgrade to BS-4, unless you have a requirement to. Or to update all your HTML when you do

**Edit**

Reading through the [SASS docs](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7), it seems the functionality has been changed to work using the comma syntax. So this would be your best option going forward.

It still generates excess CSS by doubling the number of classes, but not as bad as duplicating all your CSS

Comment: Less css does not copy the selected class into the new one ^^

Comment: @edit, then it's indeed a good idea to use scss(sass) instead since bootstrap 4 also uses scss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use less css and do the following:

```
.table-small {
    &:extend(.table-condensed);
}
```

This does not copy over the class like sass but just adds the selector:

Generated css:

```
.table-condensed,
.table-small {
    background: red;
}
```

preprocessor online: http://lesscss.org/less-preview/